# Error in hiding worksheets based on a cell value on Master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I am trying to learn the macros and building a code to hide the specific sheets by giving yes or no. used the below code but getting script error

In the master sheet, i have mentioned all the sheet names in Col H (Row#5 onwards) and mentioned "Yes" or "No" for either making visible or hiding the same

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 4 To ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Range("I" & i) = "Yes" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 2).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ElseIf ws.Range("I" & i) = "No" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 2).Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
            Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Erm... so what's not working ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The below line shows a script error.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 2).Visible = xlSheetHidden

Comment: Your are not passing the name of the sheet to Hide Properly. See the Answer

Answer (score 0):

This will Work:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 5 To ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If ws.Range("I" & i) = "Yes" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Range("H" & i).Value).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ElseIf ws.Range("I" & i) = "No" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Range("H" & i).Value).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If

    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but getting run time error type mismatch on this line. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Range("H" & i)).Visible = xlSheetHidden

Comment: Just to let you know that i have given sheet names in Col H Row#5 onwards and Yes or No in Col I against each sheet name

Comment: @Ram ...I forgot to Add `.Value` .. I have added now .. should work now

Comment: @Ram .. yes ..Noted .. Loop should be running from 5 them ..Not sure why you were trying to run it from 4.

Comment: @Ram .. Accept the Answer for people looking the similar answer. :)